# Hardware acceleration is disabled in newer selenium/node-chrome builds

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to update the browser image we use for selenium tests from `node-chrome:3.141.59-20201119` to `node-chrome:3.141.59-20210607`, but this newer version does not have hardware acceleration enabled like the older one did. I know that its not enabled because I get a relentless popup warning that it is disabled. We need hardware acceleration to be enabled for our tests to run properly, so my question is - how can I enable it?

Here are some more details:

- We're running selenium with python in docker
- `options.add_argument('--ignore-gpu-blacklist')` has no effect
- the error is `UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: Your browser currently lacks access to Hardware-Acceleration capabilities.`
- `node-chrome:3.141.59-20210128` or `v88.0.4324.96` is the highest version that has hardware acceleration

Answer (score 1):

for me (chromium-freeworld 92 and 93) the commandline option
`--enable-features=VaapiVideoDecode`
was working.

[source - from source](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/1024)

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It's now 'blocklist' not 'blacklist'

`options.add_argument('--ignore-gpu-blocklist')`

This fixed my issue.

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/